# If a set $S$ is inconsistent, does $S\vdash \alpha$ for all $\alpha$ in this system?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Let $S$ be an inconsistent set of propositional formulas.

If our system consists of the axioms:

\begin{align}
AX1&\quad (P\implies (Q \implies P))\\
AX2&\quad (((P\implies(Q\implies R))\implies((P\implies Q)\implies(P\implies R)))\\
AX3&\quad ((\neg P\implies \neg Q)\implies((\neg P \implies Q) \implies P))
\end{align}

And the only inference rule is modus ponens, does $S\vdash \alpha\, \forall \,\alpha$?

I've been trying to construct a proof for $\alpha$ given $\Gamma \vdash \gamma, \neg \gamma$ for half an hour and couldn't get anywhere, maybe there's a simple combination of axiom application which works and I'm just not seeing it.

E: 
Following Noah's advice, I got this

\begin{align}
1.&\gamma &\text{Hyp}\\
2.&\neg \gamma &\text{Hyp}\\
3.&(\gamma\implies(\neg\alpha\implies \gamma))&\text{AX1}\\
4.&(\neg\alpha\implies\gamma)&\text{MP (1,3)}\\
5.&(\neg \gamma \implies (\neg \alpha \implies \neg \gamma))&\text{AX1}\\
6.&(\neg \alpha \implies \neg \gamma)&\text{MP(2,5)}\\
7.&((\neg \alpha \implies\neg \gamma) \implies ((\neg \alpha \implies \gamma)\implies \alpha))&\text{AX3}\\
8.&((\neg \alpha \implies \gamma) \implies \alpha)) &\text{MP(6,7)}\\
9.& \alpha.&\text{MP(4,8)}\\
\end{align}

Comment: I'm not sure how to formalize this, but I think a good idea is to take $P=\alpha,Q=\gamma$ and make use of AX3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an informal sketch.

Assume we've proved $A$ and $\neg A$, and fix any proposition $P$. Then we have $$\neg P\implies \neg A,$$ since we have the stronger proposition $\neg A$ (this uses AX1). Similarly, we have $\neg P\implies A$.

So by AX3, we have $P$.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got the proof right, would you mind checking it in my edit?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Looks good to me!